# Local Storage of a website for scraping data

Tags: python, selenium

I am currently trying to get information into the Local Storage of a website for data scraping but I don't know how to do it with selenium python and I have already tried to make it by looking at (StackOverflow question) but can't really find an answer, can someone help me or can show me on discord, Thank you.
-BAD#8938

Comment: _an information into the local Storage of a website_ I have no idea what this means.  Can you explain, **specifically**, what you want to do?

Comment: When you do (ctrl + shift + i) and you go into application section there will be the local storage section

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Write to local storage:

```
localStorage.setItem('my_item','my_data_string')
```

All you need to do is to pass the string you want to store.

Comment: How do i make it print and what is the 'my_item', 'my_data_string' (sorry i am very new)